# Is there a type reserved for express().listen() and if not, can it be extracted by Typescript from return value of the function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings, tslint

When building a server with Express/Typescript I tend to appoint `express().listen` to a variable `server` so it can be sent as an argument to a function used to gracefully kill and stop server in case of any of the Node terminate signals (`SIGTERM`,`SIGINT`, `SIGHUP`). Example below:

```
this.app = express();
this.server = this.app.listen(4000, () => {});
```

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => stopHandler(this.server));
process.on('SIGINT',  () => stopHandler(this.server));
process.on('SIGHUP',  () => stopHandler(this.server));
```

```
async function stopHandler() {
  console.log('Stopping...');

  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(1);
    console.error('Stopped forcefully, not all connection was closed');
  }, 2000);

  try {
    await server.stop();
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error, 'Error during stop.');
    process.exit(1);
  }
}
```

There are other usecases where mentioned type would be useful, e.g.

```
class Server {
  private: app: Application;
  private: server; // Application.listen?
  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
  }
  ...
```

ISSUE: `noImplicitAny` throws error when proper type is not appointed.

Can return value of a function be used as a type? (whatever `app.listen()` returns)

P.S. This is my first StackOverflow question, sorry if there is already a thread about this issues or similar, or if it's somehow unproperly formatted.

Comment: `express().listen()` returns a value of `http.Server` type. Try maybe updating your dependencies (both `express` and `@types/express`) since this is typed in `express` itself.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for, thanks a lot! 
I can see now that I could've find it on listen function declaration in `@types/express-serve-static-core` as `listen(port: number, callback?: () => void): http.Server`.
Though I've also used a function property `.stop()` instead of `.close()` accidentaly. 
Just a clarification for whoever might be reading.